# Using pyproj to transform shapely data is giving me strange results

Tags: python, map-projections, utm, pyproj, epsg

I've got a polygon which looks something like this in WKT:

```
POLYGON ((-2.5079473598836624 51.34385834919997, -2.5081726654409133 51.34353499032948, -2.507909808957454 51.343441165566986, -2.507679138982173 51.34359530614682, -2.5079473598836624 51.34385834919997))
```

I'm trying to transform this from EPSG:3857 (web mercator) to EPSG:32630 (UTM 30N) to do some distance calculations on it but the results look weird:

```
wgs_proj = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:3857")
utm_proj = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:32630")
transform = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(wgs_proj, utm_proj, always_xy=True).transform
shape = shapely.wkt.loads("POLYGON ((-2.5079473598836624 51.34385834919997, -2.5081726654409133 51.34353499032948, -2.507909808957454 51.343441165566986, -2.507679138982173 51.34359530614682, -2.5079473598836624 51.34385834919997))")
boundary = shapely.ops.transform(transform, shape)
print(str(boundary))
```

This outputs:

```
POLYGON ((833976.0465009063 51.05017626883035, 833976.04627538 51.04985475944731, 833976.0465384943 51.049761471464706, 833976.0467693905 51.0499147304722, 833976.0465009063 51.05017626883035))
```

This looks to me like it's got the longitude conversion roughly right but the latitude conversion completely wrong.  The units are supposed to be in metres, I think.  So unless the shape happens to be at a latitude about 51m North of the origin of UTM30N, something has gone wrong.  Can anyone point me to what?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the data is in long-lats, not in EPSG:3857.  Almost everything online says that EPSG:3857 is what Google maps uses, but this is only true internally.  EPSG:3857 is WGS84 projected into metres.  Externally, Google still uses WGS84 long-lats, ie EPSG:4326.  Changing the origin coordinate system in the code shown in the question produces the right result.